# How to find the eigenline equation

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Matrix $A_{2\times 2} = \begin{pmatrix}24&10\\12&19\end{pmatrix}$

Eigenvalues are: $\frac{43+\sqrt{505}}{2}$  OR  $\frac{43-\sqrt{505}}{2}$

With those,

1st eigenvalue,

$$\frac{5-\sqrt{505}}{2}x + 10y = 0\\ 
12x - \frac{5-\sqrt{505}}{2}y = 0$$

2nd eigenvalue,

$$\frac{5+\sqrt{505}}{2}x + 10y = 0 \\
12x-\frac{-5+\sqrt{505}}{2}y = 0$$

Question is, how to find the eigenline based on these 4 equations accordingly?

Comment: I don't know what the word, "eigenline" means. But if $v$ is an eigenvector, then so are all the (non-zero) multiples of $v$, and they form a line (missing one point, the origin). Is that line what you mean by "eigenline"?

Comment: After some searching, it looks like an eigenline is simply a one dimensional eigenspace.

Comment: the simultaneous equation that can be derived from the 2 equations of each eigenvalue. like x + y = 0, x = y, x = 2y and so.

Comment: is the eigenline the line that is unchanged by application of the matrix? if so, use $M x = x$ where $M$ is the matrix and $x$ the vector that is unchanged

Comment: @dan, there won't be any such vector, unless 1 is an eigenvalue.

Comment: you're right @GerryMyerson - never come across eigenlines before!

Comment: Well, Kerry, let's look at your 2nd eigenvalue. The two equations you have for it are, in fact, identical, so you can use either one of them as the equation of the "eigenline" for that eigenvalue. The same would be true for the 1st eigenvalue, except you made some arithmetical error and got the equations wrong.

Comment: Any thoughts on the discussion, Kerry?

Comment: I followed what you've said, picking either equation as the eigenline and thus getting the eigenvector from it. Haven't been working out on this question for the time being though. But from the looks of it the answer seems correct !

Comment: OK, when you've worked it out to your satisfaction, let me encourage you to write it up and to post it as an answer.